# Basic probability inequality between 4 events

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, probability-inequalities

I have been asked to prove the following but am unsure if it is true:

$$\mathbb{P}(A,B,C)<\mathbb{P}(D) \implies \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) + \mathbb{P}(C) - 2 < \mathbb{P}(D)$$

I don't think this is true but am unsure... the question before this also assumed $\mathbb{P}(A), \mathbb{P}(B), \mathbb{P}(C)$ were small (i.e. less than $\frac{1}{k}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$), but I am unsure if the assumption is meant to be carried across to this question. Please could someone prove (or disprove) this for me?

Comment: The appearance of the $2$ is bothersome, given the issue involves the union of *three* sets.  We can turn the $2$ into $3$ by subtracting $1$ from both sides.  Since that leaves a non-positive number $\mathbb{P}(D)-1$ on the right, it's then natural to negate both sides, thereby reversing the inequality.  The resulting $3$ on the left hand side can be distributed equally among the three probabilities, producing an expression with a satisfactory symmetry.  Thus, **try to prove** $$(1-\mathbb{P}(A))+(1-\mathbb{P}(B))+(1-\mathbb{P}(C)) \gt 1-\mathbb{P}(D).$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implication is true. You need to use $P(A\cap B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B).$ The proof is as follows:

\begin{align*}
P(A,B,C) &= P((A\cap B)\cap C)\\
&= P(A \cap B) + P(C) - P((A \cap B) \cup C)\\
&= P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P((A \cap B) \cup C) - P(A \cup B)
\end{align*}

now, because $P((A \cap B) \cup C) \leq 1$ and $P(A \cup B) \leq 1$, we have $$P(A, B, C) \geq P(A) + P(B) + P(C) -2.$$

So $$P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - 2 \leq P(A, B, C)$$ and $$P(A,B,C) < P(D)$$implies $$P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - 2 < P(D).$$

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you!